# AWS CLI Installation failing on Windows 2019 Datacenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm not able to run AWS CLI commands. I tried installing via PIP as well as AWS from this link (https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLISetup.exe). When I execute `aws configure` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>aws configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\aws-script.py", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 69, in main
    rc = driver.main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 203, in main
    command_table = self._get_command_table()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 112, in _get_command_table
    self._command_table = self._build_command_table()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 132, in _build_command_table
    command_object=self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 672, in emit
    return self._events.emit(event_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\customizations\preview.py", line 69, in mark_as_preview
    service_name=original_command.service_model.service_name,
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 328, in service_model
    return self._get_service_model()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 345, in _get_service_model
    api_version = self.session.get_config_variable('api_versions').get(
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 234, in get_config_variable
    logical_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\configprovider.py", line 227, in get_config_variable
    return provider.provide()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\configprovider.py", line 324, in provide
    value = provider.provide()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\configprovider.py", line 383, in provide
    config = self._session.get_scoped_config()
  File "C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\runtime\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 335, in get_scoped_config
    raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (Administrator) could not be found
```

`c:\python --version` gives the following result on the same computer:

`Python 3.7.4`

I have also tried setting the path using this command:

`setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the environment variable `AWS_PROFILE` set without a profile backing the name, botocore fails to load, even preventing the `configure` option as you've seen.

You can run something like this to temporarily unset the environment variable, create the profile, then revert back to normal:

```
set _TEMP_PROFILE=%AWS_PROFILE%
set AWS_PROFILE=
aws --profile=%_TEMP_PROFILE% configure
```

> ```
> AWS Access Key ID [None]: ...
> ...
> ```

```
set AWS_PROFILE=%_TEMP_PROFILE%
set _TEMP_PROFILE=
```

And calls to `aws` should work afterwords.